# Classification model to classify large number of classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multi-class

Hello I am  very new into the field of machine learning/deep learning , and I am finding it hard to select the right model for my research.

What I am trying to build is a model to classify which subway route a user have used based on travel time and transfer time given the origin station and destination station.

Here is a description of my data set.

```
   BSEC BSTN ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5 ASTN TFtime Ttime
 69551 1001  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0 1003    399  2933
 69664 1001  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0 1006    399  2284
 66606 1001  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0 1701    118  1750
 66600 1001  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0 1701    118  1750
 66601 1001  1703  1703     0     0     0     0     0     0 1701    118  1750
 69434 1001     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 1703      0  1005
```

ASTN1,BSTN2,ASTN2...BSTN5 refers to via stations
BSTN ASTN refers to boarding and arrival stations.

I have a another data set of route information labeled.

**The problem starts here.**

I am trying to build a model that can classify which route a user have used given BSTN, ASTN, and time info BSEC, TFtime, Ttime.
There are too many labels of routes because the routes all differs for each pair of Origin Station and Destination Station.

Below are number of routes per origin station and destination station

```
   BSTN  ASTN trips    
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1   150   152     3     
2   150   153     7     
3   150   154     2     
4   150   156     2     
5   150   157     2     
6   150   158     4
```

as described there are already 20 different routes for only 5 Origin Destination pair. There are total of 109,425 pairs of origin and destination
and 236,213 number of routes. I could not give label to every 236,213 routes for the model to classify.

i tried making random forest model for every pair of Origin Destination pair.
But I was not able to tune or interpret them because there are too many type of models.

**What would be a proper model for my situation?**
Would there be a way the model could interpret given OD pair, and then perform classification within the Origin Destinatnion pair assembly?

I would really appreciate some advice or help.